# TFL API: E/Volley: [73683] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 300

Tags: android, android-volley

I am currently developing a Journey Planner app, using TFLs Unified API, for users with varying accessibility for London.

So far JSONObject/array requests that use `icsCodes`, for example https://api.tfl.gov.uk/Journey/JourneyResults/1000266/to/1000013 , instead of strings for the to and from parameters work, and I am able to get JSON from them. But any attempt to use words for arguments result in the error in the title. My intention was to return the set of disambiguation options and allow the user to select from a list, for example Westminster (London), westminster, and parse its `icsCode` in order to get the journeys relating to that location.

TFLs documentation states that the API request returns either an object to support disambiguation or an object with the requested journey results.

Below is a link to what requests with Disambiguation.Result look like.

https://api.tfl.gov.uk/Journey/JourneyResults/westminster/to/bank

Below is my code for the `JsonRequest` and where I get the error for `DisambiguationResults`:

```
private void sendJsonRequest() {
    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, getRequestUrl(10), null,
new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        listJourneys=parseJSONResponse(response);
                        adapterResults.setJourneyList(listJourneys);
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                System.out.println(error);
            }
        });
        requestQueue.add(request);
    }
```

I get this error:

> E/Volley: [73683] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 300 for https://api.tfl.gov.uk/Journey/JourneyResults/westminster/to/bank?

If anyone could point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: that means the server returned an `HTTP.300` response https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#3xx_Redirection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your server Url responses **300** code as the following screenshot (I use [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/))

[image]

So with Volley, you can use `parseNetworkError`, then get the response body inside `onErrorResponse` as in my sample code below

```
...
String url = "https://api.tfl.gov.uk/Journey/JourneyResults/westminster/to/bank/";
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(url, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        Log.i("onResponse", response.toString());
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Log.i("onErrorResponse", error.toString());
    }
}){
    @Override
    protected VolleyError parseNetworkError(VolleyError volleyError) {
        if(volleyError.networkResponse != null && volleyError.networkResponse.data != null){
            VolleyError error = new VolleyError(new String(volleyError.networkResponse.data));
            volleyError = error;
        }

        return volleyError;
    }
};
queue.add(request);
...
```

Logcat will have the JSONObject (response body) like this `I/onErrorResponse: com.android.volley.VolleyError: {"$type":"Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.JourneyPlanner.DisambiguationResult,....`

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I was looking for! Initially I was confused by the Logcat message, but as it turns out the response body was simply far longer than what could be displayed in the Android Monitor window.